# Migrate and upgrade Oracle 12.1.0.2 to 19c: UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 12.1.0.2.0

Tags: oracle

Migrating Oracle 12.1.0.2 server to Oracle 19.13.0.0 Enterprise using a new virtual machine. I set up Oracle 19, and it seems to be running fine.

Now I want to import on dump from the Oracle 12 server using expdp/impdb. I already did so with an Oracle 11 server months ago. But now I get an error:

```
UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 12.1.0.2.0
```

I'm wondering if Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 is not compatible with Oracle 19.13.0.0? I can't find any information on this issue besides this [one](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1141173_1.html), but I don't have a valid support subscription. If I export the Oracle 12 database using VERSION=11.2.0.4 and try to import this dump I get exactly the same error.

Has anybody run into a similar issue?

Comment: Try to export the database with expdp from version 19

Comment: Thanks Romeo. I copied expdp from version 19 to the Oracle 12 server and tried to run it, but I'm getting the same error message.

Comment: You can't just copy it (expdp or impdp executable). When you run expdp you can use the 12.1 database version just fine. When you import with impdp, you need to do so in an Oracle 19c home (client or database install). Are these database software installations on the same server or different servers?

Answer (score 0):

Use version parameter for export, for example:

```
expdp username tables='HR."EMPLOYEES"' directory=EXPDIR dumpfile=eployees_%U.dmp FILESIZE=64M logfile=exp_employee.log version=12.0 PARALLEL=4
```